# Python 3.5.1 import class in the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

So I am having trouble importing classes in the same directory and getting them to work properly.

I currently have the following hiearchy

- BBDriver.py
- bbsource:

  - BouncyBallEnv.py
  - Console.py
- resources:

  - misc:
  - objects:

    - Ball.py
    - Platform.py

My problem is between the 2 files in the `bbsource` directory. I have figured out how to get access from the `bbsource` directory down to the classes in the `objects` directory and vice versa but when I try to `from BouncyBallEnv import BouncyBallEnv` in the `Console` class I get the following error:

```
File "E:\PycharmProjects\BouncyBallPythonV0\bbsource\Console.py", line 5, in 
    from BouncyBallENV import BouncyBallEnv
ImportError: cannot import name 'BouncyBallEnv'
```

I have tried several things like:

`from bbsource import BouncyBallEnv`

`from bbsource.BouncyBallEnv import BouncyBallEnv`

But I can't get it to work.

The only time I could get it to work is when I did the following:

```
    import bbsource.BouncyBallEnv
    #Extra
    print(bbsource.BouncyBallEnv.BouncyBallEnv.WIDTH)
```

But there must be a better way to do it than that so that I wouldn't have to type that lengthy statement that is in the `print` statement every time that I want to use a static variable in `BouncyBallEnv`.

I am still quite confused on how the Python importing works so I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Thank you.

NOTE: Running Python 3.5.1

Answer (score 2):

the thing you need is aliases :

```
import bbsource.BouncyBallEnv as bbe
#Extra
print(bbe.WIDTH)
```

and you can't import a module with the `from ... import ...` syntax. Only attributes. It work like this :

```
import <module> [as <alias>]

or

from <module> import <attribute> [, <attribute2>...]  # import some attributes
from <module> import *                                # import everything
```

with the second one, you could have done :

```
from bbsource.BouncyBallEnv import WIDTH
# the variable WIDTH is directly loaded : watch out for collision !

print(WIDTH)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is [abosolue_import](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html) rule.

try

```
from .BouncyBallENV import BouncyBallEnv
```

to access module in relative position.

besides, there should be an `__init__.py` file under `bbsource` directory

Comment: What would the `__init__.py` file contain? And I had been told by someone on another post about package issues that in Python 3 the `__init__.py` files were unnecessary.

Comment: So does it go in every directory, or just directories that contain `.py` files?

Comment: directories with files to be imported in any scripts